# java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRBG not returning expected values

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage

I'm trying to use the [BufferedImage.getRGB](http://j.mp/bufferedimagergb) method with seven parameters to read an area of pixels and to get their colors. Sounds simple enough, but for some reason it just won't work for me. Here's a short, self contained, compilable example:

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BufferedImageTest extends JPanel {
BufferedImage image;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedImageTest mainClass = new BufferedImageTest();
    mainClass.run();
}

private void run() {
    initWindow();
    // Create image:
    image = new BufferedImage(5, 5, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    int[] red = new int[25];
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        red[i] = Color.RED.getRGB();
    image.setRGB(1, 0, 3, 5, red, 0, 0);

    // Read image:
    int[] rgbArray = new int[25];
    int w = image.getWidth();
    int h = image.getHeight();
    image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, rgbArray, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < rgbArray.length; i++) {
        Color c = new Color(rgbArray[i]);
        System.out.print("(" + c.getRed() + "," + c.getGreen() + "," + c.getBlue() + ")");
        if (i % 5 == 4)
            System.out.println("");
    }
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(image, 5, 5, null);
}

private void initWindow() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(this);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(40, 60);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

In the *run()* method I first create a very simple 5 by 5 pixel image like this:

[image: example image]

That goes fine. I then try to read in the pixels of that image, and that doesn't work almost at all. It only gets the first line of pixels correctly, then displays the rest as black. The output of the printing loop is:

```
(0,0,0)(255,0,0)(255,0,0)(255,0,0)(0,0,0)
(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)
(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)
(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)
(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)
```

when I would expect it to be entirely like the first line. What am I missing here? I have tried writing it all over from the scratch and playing with the "scanline" and "offset" parameters in the *getRGB* call, but nothing seems to work. I'm running Java 7 on Windows 7, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the correct scansize to get all the lines:

```
image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, rgbArray, 0, w);
```

Look here: [BufferedImage#setRGB()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) and [BufferedImage#getRGB()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: Well, that does seem to do the trick. Thanks! Although I still don't understand why setting the scansize to anything but _h_ gets me those crazy values?? And why is it that my setRGB call works just fine when the scansize is 0? The problem must be that I (still) have no idea what "scanline stride for the rgbArray" actually means, as that's how the variable is defined in the documentation.

Comment: @ZeroOne While the answer works for the 5x5 example, you typically want to set the scanSize or scanline stride to `w` (not `h`). The reason for this parameter is to allow copying a region of pixels into a possible larger array of pixels (as an example).